# Error: cannot 'squash' without a previous commit You can fix this with 'git rebase --edit-todo' and then run 'git rebase --continue'

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a below commits in bitbucket,i wanted to squash all the commits in to one  commits.

When i do `git rebase -i HEAD~5`,it is showing all the commits in reverse order on git bash,where the last commit ie is Commit 5 is listed last.

```
pick 104e52ffdb IA-31774 Commit 1
pick 157be0f3b3 IA-31774 Commit 2
pick 4619cf38be IA-31774 Commit 3
pick e89937fca9 IA-31774 Commit 4
pick 38c54ea317 IA-31774 Commit 5
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I tried below options.

```
s 104e52ffdb IA-31774 Commit 1
s 157be0f3b3 IA-31774 Commit 2
s 4619cf38be IA-31774 Commit 3
p e89937fca9 IA-31774 Commit 4
r 38c54ea317 IA-31774 Commit 5
```

I tried the above option,i got the below error.

> error: cannot 'squash' without a previous commit You can fix this with
> 'git rebase --edit-todo' and then run 'git rebase --continue'. Or you
> can abort the rebase with 'git rebase --abort'.

Can any one plese help me how to squash all the 5 commits in to single commits,also let me know
the steps to be followed for squashing all the 5 commits in to single commit.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The `squash` command means: "Squash this commit into the previous commit." That is, your first `s` should remain `pick` so that your subsequent `s` commands find some commit before them into which they can be squashed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, lines are executed in order up to down.

In order to squash everything this should work:

```
r 104e52ffdb IA-31774 Commit 1
s 157be0f3b3 IA-31774 Commit 2
s 4619cf38be IA-31774 Commit 3
s e89937fca9 IA-31774 Commit 4
s 38c54ea317 IA-31774 Commit 5
```

You reword and keep the first commit and squash all other.
And if you want to delete messages of all your commits after commit 1, you should use `f` for `fixup` instead of squash..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..I will try that..                sine you have mentioned to use fixup if I want to delete messages of all my commits instead of squash.                                                                   1.if I use fix up,all my commit messages will be deleted is it...also I have comments received from developer,will it be erased.               Please confirm.                                                           2.Can u plz let me know wat reword will do,if I do it for first commit as mentioned by you.  Please confi

Comment: @SSL: which comments? The ones on the commit messages or on bitbucket or github? You used reword in you post, it allows you to change the commit message without changing the content.